# How to specify click callback?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have interface that describes a button:

```
export interface IButtonConfig {
  text: string,
  class: string,
  click?: any
}
```

I need to set click property as callback to use it like this:

```
click(cb) {
  cb();
}
 click(data => {
     // get Callback result here
})
```

How to to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different signatures in your second lot of code (the example usage).

One looks like:

```
export interface IButtonConfig {
  text: string,
  class: string,
  click?:(data: any) => void
}
```

The other looks like:

```
export interface IButtonConfig {
  text: string,
  class: string,
  click?:() => void
}
```

It looks like you want to do this?

```
const click = (cb: () => any) => (data: any) => { 
  const callbackResult = cb()
  ... do something with data and the result of the callback
})
```

This allows you to bind a function in to the click handler (I think that's what it is?), so that when the click event handler (`(data: any) => void`) is called, the first callback is executed and the result of that callback is available with the click event data in the handler function.

Is that what you are trying to achieve?

If so, the signature is:

```
export interface IButtonConfig {
  text: string,
  class: string,
  click?: (cb: () => any) => (data: any) => void
}
```